# How to capture grouping in an expression?

Tags: python, expression, grouping, parentheses

I'm trying to record grouping in expressions, like:

```
condition_a = Condition( "x = 5 ")
condition_b = Condition( "y > 6 " )
condition_c = Condition( "z = 7 " )

condition_c & ( condition_a | condition_b )
```

These are expressions a user can write to configure a SQL query, so the above would ultimately be expressed as `x = 5 AND (y > 6 OR z = 7)`.

I tried this:

```
class Condition( object ) :
    def __init__( self, expr ) :
        ....

    def __and__( self , other ) :
        print 'calling and'
        ....
        return self

    def __or__( self , other ) : 
        print 'calling or'
        ....
        return self

    def __call__( self , other ) :
        print 'calling ()'
        ....
        return self
```

I would expect this code :

```
condition_a = Condition( "x = 5 ")
condition_b = Condition( "y > 6 " )
condition_c = Condition( "z = 7 " )
condition = condition_c & ( condition_a | condition_b )
expected =  "z = 7 AND ( x = 5 OR y > 6 )"
```

to print the `calling ()` but it does not. I just see :

```
calling or
calling and
```

It seems I am not using a call, so something like `condition_a(1)`, so `__call__` is not called.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? You can check the expected which is what I want to have (*and* and *or* works, it's just I don't have the parenthesis around part of the expression).

Comment: @ghostrider: You'll have to explain more precisely what you want to actually happen. If you specifically want to handle parentheses (which isn't possible in the way you want), I don't think you're going about this the right way. What if you write `x = condition_a | condition_b` and then `condition = condition_c & x`? It's identical to what you have, but with no parentheses. Creating an `Expression` class or something similar and having `c1 | c2` produce a `Expression(c1, '|', c2)` is enough to "encode" the parentheses.

Comment: @Blender yes I want to specifically handle parentheses - so probably need to change my approach. Well on the example you have that's fine - want I want is that if the user puts `()` around a query - then there are shown in the produced query. will edit again with more details.

Comment: @ghostrider: Python doesn't expose any direct way to see the exact syntax used. You could instead parse the user input as a string instead of defining operations between objects. Out of curiosity, why do you even care about parentheses? `x AND y` and `((((((x) AND (y))))))` are equivalent.

Comment: @Blender that's true but `a1 Or a2 And b`  the order matters in SQL execution. this is intepreted as `a1 Or (a2 And b)` and I want user to have the option to explicitly use it as `(a1 Or a2) And b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `(...)` parentheses in your expression are not a call expression. They are just there to group your expressions.

Python does not preserve grouping parentheses. They only are used by the parser to build an *abstract syntax tree*, and grouping influences in what order expressions are executed.

The expression

```
A & B | C
```

is parsed into a tree of `BinOp` objects, like this:

```
      |
    /   \
   &      C
 /   \
A     B
```

`&` binds more tightly here, so `A & B` is executed before the `|` operator is executed. That's because the [`|` operator has a lower *precedence* than `&`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Parentheses tell the parser to build separate trees for everything between `(...)` before putting that into the tree, so the expression

```
A & (B | C)
```

becomes

```
   &
 /   \
A     |
    /   \
  B       C
```

The parentheses are gone, all that is left is the tree of expressions, and Python knows know in what order you need to execute those expressions; the `|` is executed first, on `B` and `C`, and the result of this expression is then used in the `&` operator.

You can look at those AST objects with the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html):

```
>>> import ast
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse('A & B | C').body[0].value)))
BinOp(
    left=BinOp(
        left=Name(id='A', ctx=Load()),
        op=BitAnd(),
        right=Name(id='B', ctx=Load())
    ),
    op=BitOr(),
    right=Name(id='C', ctx=Load()))
)
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse('A & (B | C)').body[0].value))
BinOp(
    left=Name(id='A', ctx=Load()),
    op=BitAnd(),
    right=BinOp(
        left=Name(id='B', ctx=Load()),
        op=BitOr(),
        right=Name(id='C', ctx=Load())
    )
)
```

(I unwrapped the outer `Module` and `Expr` objects to focus on the `BinOp` trees, and manually indented the nested objects).

and you can see the order of operations change when you look at the resulting bytecode with the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html):

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('A & B | C', '', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (A)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (B)
              4 BINARY_AND
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (C)
              8 BINARY_OR
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(compile('A & (B | C)', '', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (A)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (B)
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (C)
              6 BINARY_OR
              8 BINARY_AND
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

(`LOAD_NAME` puts a value on the stack, and `BINARY_OR` and `BINARY_AND` take the top 2 values from the stack and push back the result).

All this means that *parentheses cannot be retrieved this way*. They are gone, they were only there to inform the order of operations.

What you need to do then, is maintain the *syntax tree*; you can still reconstruct that from the execution. You could just *always* include parentheses when you then output your result:

```
class Expr(object):
    def __or__(self, other):
        return BinOp(self, '|', other)

    def __and__(self, other):
        return BinOp(self, '&', other)

class BinOp(Expr):
    def __init__(self, left, oper, right):
        self.left, self.oper, self.right = left, oper, right

    def __repr__(self):
        return "({} {} {})".format(self.left, self.oper, self.right)

class Condition(Expr):
    def __init__(self, expr):
        self.expr = expr

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.expr
```

When printing a `BinOp` object, you'll *always* get parentheses:

```
>>> condition_a = Condition( "x = 5 ")
>>> condition_b = Condition( "y > 6 " )
>>> condition_c = Condition( "z = 7 " )
>>> condition_c & ( condition_a | condition_b )
(z = 7  | (x = 5  | y > 6 ))
>>> condition_c & condition_a | condition_b
((z = 7  | x = 5 ) | y > 6 )
```

This is *fine*, because the SQL parser treats parentheses the same way; just to group expressions.

The next step is to add *precedence* information to your binary operators. You can then decide if you have to have parentheses around a sub-expression or not; only when the left sub-expression has a lower precedence, or the right has a lower or equal precedence, would you need them:

```
# Condition stays the same

class Expr(object):
    precedence = float('inf')

    def __or__(self, other):
        return BinOp(self, '|', other)

    def __and__(self, other):
        return BinOp(self, '&', other)

class BinOp(Expr):
    def __init__(self, left, oper, right):
        self.left, self.oper, self.right = left, oper, right
        self.precedence = '|&'.index(oper)  # 0 or 1

    def __repr__(self):
        left, right = self.left, self.right
        if left.precedence < self.precedence:
            left = '({})'.format(left)
        if right.precedence <= self.precedence:
            right = '({})'.format(right)
        return "{} {} {}".format(left, self.oper, right)
```

Now parentheses only show up when the expression requires them:

```
>>> condition_c & ( condition_a | condition_b )
z = 7  & (x = 5  | y > 6 )
>>> condition_c & condition_a | condition_b
z = 7  & x = 5  | y > 6
>>> condition_c & (condition_a & condition_b)
z = 7  & (x = 5  & y > 6 )
```

If you are going to extend this system (adding in more operator types), you'll have to expand on the concept of precedence there; the above example only has `0` and `1` for the binary operators, but you'll have to naturally expand on these values if you have more.

I'd also *strongly* urge you to look at [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), which already implements all this, and much more.

Comment: thank you very much! will read more info on the above but it seems to do what I wanted!